# Show specific variable at the Watch Window of a vector of structs

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

Suppose I have a `std::vector<Foo>` of size `30`, the `Foo` struct is defined as:

```
struct Foo {
    int a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m; //many fields
    // ...
};
```

Is it possible to "watch" only the contents of the field `g` for all the elements of the vector?

I think that an expression at the Watch Window like:

```
(v)._Myfirst[$index].g
//v would be the variable holding the vector being debugged
```

would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

If you add visualizer info for `Foo` to %VSINSTALLDIR%\Common7\Packages\Debugger\autoexp.dat, you should get the desired effect just by watching `v`.

So for example, say you have `v` populated with 3 `Foo`s having `g` values of 111, 222 and 333.  If you add the following to the end of autoexp.dat:

```
Foo {
    preview (
        $c.g
    )
}
```

the Watch Window looks like:

[image: VS10 Watch Window]

Or you could add:

```
Foo {
    preview (
        #("g = ", $c.g)
    )
}
```

yielding:

[image: VS10 Watch Window]

Comment: This is nice, but the problem is that, for every Foo, I will also want to watch the other variables (but in different watch entries). So having to add a new visualizer for every variable is kinda prohibitive.
Unless the debugger can load visualizers on the fly so I could write a simple VS addin that does that for me...